# list all current user sessions for an app server in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am using marklogic 9.0-8.2

We know marklogic tracks users login monitoring like last successful login and last unsuccessful login using "last login" database. We need to check if there a way to list all the current user sessions for an app server ? `xdmp:get-current-user()` didn't help much.

Comment: Have you tried xdmp:get-session-field-names()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdmp:get-current-user` only lists information about a user

[xdmp:server-status](https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/xdmp:server-status) will return the information about user requests on a per host basis

Comment: Note though that server-status only lists currently running requests, not user sessions. To my knowledge that information is not exposed anywhere. Also, user sessions are tied to a host. In theory one user could have sessions on multiple hosts, though that is something one would want to avoid..